# jQuery toggle content-div from menubar

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, toggle

I'm having trouble getting jQuery to allow only one content-DIV to be visible at a time. So that clicking between the menu buttons (about, newsletter, contact) this will allow only one content-DIV to be visible.

--- Then the content-DIV needs to hide when the associated menu button is clicked (like it does currently).

--- Upon clicking the header 'alliteration', any content-DIVs that are open need to hide.

```
 $('#collapse_about').hide();
 $('#collapse_newsletter').hide();
 $('#collapse_contact').hide();

 $('#menu1').click(function() {
  $('#collapse_about').slideToggle(400);
   return false;
  });

 $('#menu2').click(function() {
  $('#collapse_newsletter').slideToggle(400);
   return false;
  });

 $('#menu3').click(function() {
  $('#collapse_contact').slideToggle(400);
   return false;
  });
```

*I understand that this is a pretty simple bit of code... but the form of it evades me. Any help is much appreciated.*

Comment: It seems like you need an effect along the lines of the accordian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head I would assign all of the menus the same class such as class1. Then make the div slideUp which has a callback function. When the slideUp is finished it will slide down the correct panel.

```
  $('#menu1').click(function() {
$(".class1").slideUp(function() {
  $('#collapse_about').slideDown(400);
   });
  });

 $('#menu2').click(function() {
$(".class1").slideUp(function() {
  $('#collapse_newsletter').slideDown(400);
   });
  });

 $('#menu3').click(function() {
$(".class1").slideUp(function() {
  $('#collapse_contact').slideDown(400);
   });
  });
```

Edit: This is a start but doesn't entirely do as you are asking:(
Here is the demo on jsfiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UqM5d/)

Comment: that assumes a class1 item is visible at the start - which it is not!

Comment: @redsquare, exactly, the callback parameter for slideUp works when the element is done animating. If class1 is already hidden there is no animation so the callback gets called immediatly, in other words it acts like a click function.

Comment: Sorry - got it wrong - what I meant to say was that the slideDown would get called n times (1 for each .class1 element)

Comment: @redsquare, I'm calling slideDown via Id, it's slideup that is being called on the class. If you call slideUp on an element that's already hidden, the user won't see any feedback.

Comment: sure but it is not a good practise to get into. It still does work for no reason, and with different code (e.g slideToggle) would cause repetitive actions